# MS Access Report Unbound DLookup Not Updating Unless Clicked

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have to use an unbound textbox in an Access 2013 report, because although the data I am looking for is in a related table, it is possible that there may not be a matching record in the child table.

Basically, I have a master inventory table, which has a primary key, and a unique index "Stock#". This table has data related to that individual stock number, and there are another 5 related tables, which contain other data related to that stock number, such as cost, sales, location, etc.  When an inventory record is created in the master table, a child record is created in 4 tables, with some basic initial data, and they are all locked with a one to one relationship.  I chose to structure data like this to avoid record locking conflicts, and increase performance in a multi-user environment, despite my use of unbound forms.

Here is my problem:

I am designing an inventory snapshot report, and it has data from all five tables.  One of the tables with a one - one relationship is not created with the inventory records.  It comes from an external source (a key tracking machine).  The problem is, sometimes a stock number may exist in the database, but it has not yet made its way to the key machine.  Not a big deal in most cases, except when designing a bound report.  My bound report's query selects data from all the inventory tables, including the key data table.  Lets assume I have 200 stock numbers in the inventory table, with 200 identical records in the other 4 tables.  However the key data table has only 195 records.  This will mean that the report will only select the stock numbers, and related data, where an exact match exists in all five tables (195 records).  My solution for this was to create a dlookup in an unbound textbox, with the following syntax:

```
=DLookUp("[KeyTrakExport]![CurrentlyOutTo]","[KeyTrakExport]","    [KeyTrakExport]![Stock#]= " & Chr(34) & [Reports]![TestInvtReport]![Stock#] & Chr(34))
```

I have tried many variations of this, with and without Chr(34), and there are at least 5 working methods to look up key data.  However, the problems is, the only way to have it actually retrieve the values (if any) is to click in each key data textbox on the report.  I have tried many different requery/update methods, and using VBA to retrieve the value and plant it in the textbox.  None of these work properly, and if anything they assign the same value to all the records on the report.  I know Access is limited in many ways, but I have to use it for a few months before switching to real development.  Does anyone know how to make this dlookup function update as soon as the report loads, and whenever its refreshed?  Or should I scrap it and go with a continuous form designed like a report?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found the solution.  I already tried this syntax before, to no avail, but after installing the most recent Office updates and rebooting, this worked.

```
=DLookUp("[CurrentlyOutTo]","[KeyTrakExport]","[Stock#]=  '" & [Reports]!    [TestInvtReport]![Stock#] & "'")
```